# Is this physical collection class that contains only static methods an Anti-Pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm trying to figure out if I should continue on with a current pattern in an application I'm working in, or refactor this into something else.

I have a set of collection classes off a generic base of List. These classes have public constructors but contain only static methods that return collections. They look like this:

```
public class UserObjCollection : BaseCollection<UserObj>
{
  public static UserObjCollection GetAllUserObj()
  {
    UserObjCollection obj = new UserObjCollection();
    obj.MapObjects(new UserObjDataService().GetAllUserObj());
    return obj;
  }
}
```

Is this a Pattern or Anti-Pattern and what are the merits of this over a straight factory pattern?

**EDIT:** I'm leaning towards removing these physical collections, and moving their static methods into the data access layer (UserObjDataService). There are a lot of object types so I need to keep the code in seprate places, but they almost all have a 1 to 1 factory object in the datalayer.

Comment: This looks more like the repository pattern. It may very well be acceptable in your scenario to have a static repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UserObjCollection does not add anything to `BaseCollection<UserObj>`, objects of both classes are identical, functionality wise. It would be nicer to remove `UserObjCollection` and put `GetAllUserObj()` in `BaseCollection<T>` (Factory Method). You can also put `GetAllUserObj()` in a seperate static class. I don't think the abstract factory pattern is necessary here, as you're not creating different object families.

The reason why I would remove `UserObjCollection` is because this class might cause other developers to add to it without thinking it through. If it later turns out that `UserObjCollection` is in fact sufficiently different from `BaseCollection<UserObj>` that it warrants a separate class, you can re-add `UserObjCollection` then.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to call this factory method pattern (possibly incorrectly).

Because I am doing only Test Driven Development these days, I tend to avoid it, because it is very difficult to test. In your static method you create a lot of concrete classes, so you can't really mock any of these objects. Moreover you can't mock the whole static method either, which makes all the classes fairly tightly coupled. A straight factory patterns would at least allow to mock the whole factory object, which makes testing much easier.